# Serial consumption between message types

Tags: masstransit

I have a MassTransit system that will consume 2 message types, one for a batch process, the other for CRUD operations on a single entity. Whilst the batch process is running, the CRUD operations should not be de-queued.

Is this possible to achieve using MassTransit? It seems the exchange binding -> type name, would potentially make this behavior difficult.

A solution would be to use one message type to denote both operations and then interrogate the message contents to discern between single and batch but this feels like a code smell. Also, this would require concurrency configuration to ensure only one consumer is ever active.

Can anyone help with an alternative solution here? Essentially, we need to pause all message consumption whilst an event driven process is running.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By pause, do you mean that you want the CRUD operations to be able to occur without being blocked by the batch process? Because if it's only a matter of not having the two separate messages get in the way of each other, the most logical solution is using two separate queues, one receive endpoint for the batch process and another for the CRUD operations.

Now, if you truly need to separate the batch process such that it doesn't happen *during* the CRUD operations, that will require more work. And what if you receive a CRUD operation while the batch process is already running?

I think the separate queues is your best solution, however.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response. Essentially I need the system to not dequeue any CRUD messages whilst the batch processing is running. Then resume afterwards. Is this possible? Thanks again.

Comment: You'd be best off creating two services, one for each, and stopping the CRUD one until the batch one completes.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I expected a similar solution,